# Azure cosmos db - consistently level for Disater recovery scenario

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I have an Azure cosmos db in WEST US and all my applications are deployed on the same region.

Now I am tring to setup a disaster recovery system by

1. Deploying the application on the EAST US
2. Applications will be inactive until a disaster happens
3. DBs will be enabled with Geo-replication so that data is up to date on the disaster recovery region

Having said that the EAST US region will never be used until the disaster that takes the WEST US down.

I want to know what would be appropriate azure cosmos db consistently to be used in this scenario.

There are five types of consistency levels provided by Azure and I want to select the consistency which shouldn't impact the application performance and keep the EAST US upto date without lacking.

1. Eventual
2. Consistent Prefix
3. Session
4. Bounded Staleness
5. Strong

I am considering the Bounded consistency however the syncs only every 5 minutes, leaving 5 minutes data loss at least.

Is there a better consistency configuration used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot keep 2 regions up to date and at the same time have no impact on performance.

To keep data up to date you must write to both regions at the same time. This takes longer than writing to a single region first and letting the other region catch up eventually.

Suggest you start with looking at how cosmosdb supports high availability https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/high-availability

How consistency levels works is documented here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/consistency-levels

Comment: FYI this should be a comment, not an answer (at least the links you provided). There's no way to objectively and definitively answer the OP's question, as it's very broad.

Comment: I thought that the secondary region is kept up-to-date with in few seconds, is that not correct?

Comment: Say I opted for the Bounded Staleness with max 5 minutes, how often it sync up with secondary region and what would be the data loss max?

Comment: Then your max data loss would be 5 minutes. Bounded Staleness determines how far behind all replicas are.